# There is no mtimes attribute on webpack5 compiler.watchFileSystem.watcher, how can I get the list of changed files?

Tags: webpack-5

```
webpack4 compiler.watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes
```

Obtain the list of changed files and do some follow-up processing. Currently migrating webpack5, it is found that the property `mtimes` is not available on webpack5.

Is there any alternative property or method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler.modifiedFiles has been added (next to Compiler.removedFiles) to make it easier to reference the changed files.

Compiler.modifiedFiles can help me